# How to properly test Spring @Transactional timeout

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, transactional

I got a simple API loading data from a `PostgreSQL` database and a simple CRUD service/repository (all spring-boot based). I've marked my create/update methods in the service layer as:

```
@Transactional(timeout=5)
public void create(Entity x){
   ... 
   repository.save(x) 
}
```

How can I test (integration testing, by the way) the condition under the timeout exception would be thrown? My repository is an extension of `CrudRepository`.

Something like `doTimeout(6000).when(repository).save(...)`

Comment: You don't need to test transactional timeout.  It is part of the Spring system, not your system.

Comment: @DwB I kind of have your opinion, but OTOH I agree with all aspects described in this post: http://the-music-of-time.blogspot.com.br/2012/10/writing-unit-tests-to-ensure-your.html. I like to think about the contracts I'm describing in my methods and removing this would change it greatly.

Answer (score 0):

You should parameterise the timeout value and provide it through a profile, then set it to your test value in your integration tests. That allows you to have production values in your production profile, and test values in your test profile.

For example, in a profile called `application-test.yaml` have an entry:

```
postgres.config:
  timeout: 10
```

Then replace `timeout=5` with `"${postgres.config.10:20}"`. The `20` specifies a default value if the application is started without a specific profile.